# Suggestions on optimizing the EGit on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am using EGit on fairly large and complex set of Java projects (more than a million line of code) and a decade worth of history. 
Here I am facing serious performance issues with EGit, as even small one line change in the Java file causes EGit to re-index for couple of minutes which is slowing the entire system.
Indeed, even git command line is bit slow as "git status" takes around a minute from command line, but I can live with this performance issue, & EGit commit dialog slowness issue ([link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=327913)). As I can use git command line to commit, and update, but I don't want to tradeoff my Eclipse performance as that does affect productivity.

The following is what I have tried by doing Googling and asking people around:

1. Added all classes folder in the exclude file. Indeed tried putting the classes folderin .gitignore as well for time being.
2. Gave Egit enough time to finish indexing by keeping the machine ON for a day.
3. Git staging, history and all other Eclipses views are closed in the Eclipse workbench while doing development.
4. Did "git gc" - It made difference on the command line performance, but hardly any difference for EGit.
5. Unchecked Label decorator for Git. Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Label Decorations.
6. Removed the cygwin from path, as read somewhere in the forum that JGit might be using cygwin for path conversion.
7. Increased window cache from 10 to 70m in Eclipse (Preferences -> Team -> Git -> window cache).

PS: Git repository is pointing to svn remote repository. Also, I am git newbie so might have made some mistake in setup, so please feel free to point out anything.

Here is my system information, I don't have much fancy hardware specs, but some RAM to spare (8GB).

- git-gui version 0.16 GITGUID
- git version: 1.7.10.mysysgit.1
- JDK 1.6_025
- Eclipse version: 3.7.2 Java EE version with parameters -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m
- EGit: 1.3.0.201202151440
- Windows 7  Processor: Core 2 Duo 2.6GHZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the problem between CVCS (Centralized VCS) and DVCS (Distributed) VCS:

- One SVN repo can contains GB worth of data.
- a Git repo should be kept small, and take advantage of [submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html) in order to represents, through multiple Git repos.

I suspect lots of repos might perform better than one giant Git repo. Otherwise, synchronization issues start happening, like in [bug 323839](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=323839).

But that means managing the (simplified) synchronization between Git repos and the one SVN repo manually, through an SVN workspace from which you are copying from to yourGit repos, or to which you are copying Git repos new evolutions back to the SVN workspace to commit in.

Comment: VonC - Agree, but there is some issue with Egit implementation for sure, as same large git repo performs pretty good on Linux box with a IntelliJ), though I agree Linux file systems are much faster. So, can I create one central Git repo which is clone of SVN, and then have multiple small Git repo from the giant central Git repo?

Comment: @Hemant no, you cannot (not with the possibility of committing back to the SVN repo). You can define one Git repo which declares all the small ones as submodules, but there won't be any link with an SVN repo. That leaves a manual synchronization mechanism.

Comment: Vonc - Thank you for clarifying it. I'll keep exploring my options ... also I hope Egit team do some performance tuning faster.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not quite your problem but this page comes up on google with respect to egit performance.
Once source of performance problems is untracked (indexed?) files.
Make certain that you don't have large numbers of untracked files in the local directory tree as this seriously impacts egit performance. I removed a director with 10K + files and commit performance went from taking 1+ minute to open the commit dialog to taking a couple of seconds.

Comment: I don't have any untracked files in my repository. I am working on the huge repository which have around ~28k Java files and 136k commits, but most of them should be packed already.

Comment: Try cloning `git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git`. A Linux kernel checkout has around 45k files and the kernel has way over 300k commits. A repo with 28k files and 136k commits is a big one, not huge.

Comment: For a huge repo, try cloning `https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev.git`. The clone will need to transfer around 1.5GB of data over wire alone...

Comment: The Mozilla/Gecko repo checkout has 97k files (681MB of source files) and 370k commits. Using 64 bit Ubuntu on a HDD (instead of SSD), `git status` takes around 0.4 seconds with hot caches and 31 seconds with cold caches (after doing `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` as root). Doing a `git diff` takes 0.15 seconds after modifying a single file within the working directory. `git checkout -b test` takes 0.7 seconds, `git add -u` takes 0.3 seconds and `time git commit -m test`. If *anything local* takes 60 seconds with git, you're doing it wrong or your operating system needs to be fixed.

Comment: Above performance numbers were for command line `git version 1.7.9.5`. I'm pretty sure EGit does not do that well with repositories this big.